# Initializing the Label.Text in the Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `processorCountLabel` that is placed on my Windows Forms `MainForm`. I want to initialize that label's text with value from a function. Where is the best place to do it and why?

Should I put it in the `MainForm` constructor, the `MainForm_Load()` event or override the `OnLoad` method?

Answer (score 2):

If you set it up in the designer, it gets initialized in the `InitializeComponent` call inside the form's constructor.  If you do it in code, you can either initialize it in the constructor (before the form is *created* (i.e., has a window handle) or in the Form's Load event handler (after the form is created but before it's shown).

Personally, I set up most of the static properties of my forms' controls in the designer and let the WinForms infrastructure take care of things.

Answer (score 1):

Best place is in the Load event.

This way, everything is loaded and constructed. But the form is not yet visible.